# Is there an easy way to create an AI opponent for the Othello game?

Tags: game-design, ai, competition

Is there a well known AI technique to create an opponent in the game Othello (aka Reversi)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard game-tree search techniques will beat most human players easily.  Othello has less combinatorial complexity than chess, and humans have a harder time forecasting the future in Othello.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi#Computer_opponents_and_research

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Othello